# Angularjs: Cursor jumps in contenteditable after a html link is added

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cursor, contenteditable

If a link is added to the ng-model bound to a contenteditable div, any input forces the cursor to bounce:

Example: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gzESyO?p=preview)

What causes this issue? 
I understand if the cursor bounces when the link is created for the first time as element's html is re-plotted. However, here it is changes position every time a user writes any character.

**HTML:**

```
<div contenteditable
      name="myWidget" 
      ng-bind-html="userContent"
      ng-model="userContent"
      strip-br="true"
      required></div>
```

**Javacript:**

```
app.directive('contenteditable', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
      require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

        // Specify how UI should be updated
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngModel.$viewValue || ''));
        };

        // Listen for change events to enable binding
        element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
          scope.$evalAsync(read);
        });
        read(); // initialize

        // Write data to the model
        function read() {
          var html = element.html();
          // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
          // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
          if ( attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>' ) {
            html = '';
          }
          ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
        }
      }
    };
  }]);

  app.controller('testController', ['$scope','$timeout', function($scope,$timeout) {

      $timeout(function(){
        $scope.userContent = '<a href="something.com">something.com</a>';
      });

  }]);
```

**UPDATE:** I can utilize Rangy library to save cursor position however, algorithm does take some time to restore position causing spelling errors. Check out this [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/Zpe6UL?p=preview)

Comment: You replace the html in `render` so browser has lost selection point. What are you trying to do with this directive?

Comment: Normally this kind of thing could be resolved by using `element[0].selectionStart` to capture the cursor pos and then `element[0].setSelectionRange()` to reset the cursor after you update the value. However, by using a `contenteditable` `<div>` I think it makes that solution unavailable.

Comment: @charlietfl @ Lex please check out the update in the question.